# Opposite of 'this'

Tags: this, infowindow

This is the command to open an InfoWindow on Google Maps.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this, 'click', function () {
        open(map, this);
});
```

Where it says open:

```
open(map, this);
```

Obviously, it opens the InfoWindow for THIS marker, but is there an opposite function i can use to make sure all other Markers InfoWindows are closed?

Comment: So you want to check if all the others are closed? Try using a `for` loop. There is no opposite to `this`, though I am tempted to say use `that` despite the fact that it would cause an error.

Comment: i was looking for a way of saying 'Open this one, and close the rest' if that makes sense.

Comment: If there is a way to get an array or list of all InfoWindows currently open, you can just iterate through it. Like I said, I don't know anything about the Google API so that's all I can think of.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help! But the answer below seems legit. Try that, too.

Answer (score 0):

Just make one InfoWindow, not a new one for every marker. If you open the InfoWindow for the new marker, it gets removed from the old one.
In a surrounding scope (eg global):

```
    var myInfo = new google.maps.InfoWindow(...);
```

in the code where you add your marker:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(this, 'click', function () {
      myInfo.setContent(...); //set marker specific content
      myInfo.open(map, this);
    });
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean with universal, but just create one InfoWindow per map. Then in the handler function before opening it set the new content.